# Merge two list to make a dictionary based on elements of one list as key (with duplicates) and other as value

Tags: python, dictionary

I have two list storing `key` and `values` like this:

```
key_list=['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
value_list=['(a)one', '(a)two', '(a)three', '(a)four', '(a)five', '(a)six', '(b)one', '(b)two', '(c)one', '(c)two', '(d)one']
```

I'm trying to merge both and get new lists like this:

```
new key ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
new value ['(a)one--(a)two--(a)three--(a)four--(a)five--(a)six', '(b)one--(b)two', '(c)one--(c)two',(d)one]
```

After that its possible to make dictionary witouth delete dublicate.

I tried this code. Can you help me?

```
key_list=['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
value_list=['(a)one', '(a)two', '(a)three', '(a)four', '(a)five', '(a)six', '(b)one', '(b)two', '(c)one', '(c)two', '(d)one']
#-------------------------------
new_key=[]
new_value=[]
check=[]
for x,index in enumerate(key_list):
    if index in new_key:
        check.append(index)
        print("-dublicate \nx",x,"index",index,"\nadd check",check)
        try:
            x=x-1
            if check[x-1] == check[x]:
                print("inside the test")
                add=(value_list[x])+"--"+(value_list[x+1])
                new_value.append(add)
                del value_list[x]
        except:
            continue
    else:
        try:
            print("uniq element x - index:", x, index)
            new_key.append(index)
            new_value.append(value_list[x])
        except:
            continue
print("new key", new_key)
print("new value",new_value)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) to set the default value as `list` for each of your key in `dict` object, and then you can map  key-value from your lists.

**To map key and value based on the index of each list**, use `zip()`:

```
from collections import defaultdict

key_list=['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
value_list=['(a)one', '(a)two', '(a)three', '(a)four', '(a)five', '(a)six', '(b)one', '(b)two', '(c)one', '(c)two', '(d)one']

my_dict = defaultdict(list)
            
for key, value in zip(key_list, value_list):
    my_dict[key].append(value)
```

**To map key and value based on string prefix of value as "*(key)*"**, use `string.startswith(...)`:

```
my_dict = defaultdict(list)
for key in set(key_list):
    for value in value_list:
        if value.startswith('({})'.format(key)):
            my_dict[key].append(value)
```

For the mentioned lists, `my_dict` will hold below value from both the aboved codes:

```
{
    'a': ['(a)one', '(a)two', '(a)three', '(a)four', '(a)five', '(a)six'], 
    'b': ['(b)one', '(b)two'], 
    'c': ['(c)one', '(c)two'], 
    'd': ['(d)one']
}
```

Now you can get your `new_key` and `new_value` list from `my_dict` in desired format as:

```
new_key = my_dict.keys()
# where `new_key` will hold:
# ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']

new_value = ['--'.join(value) for value in my_dict.values()]
# where `new_value` will hold:
# ['(a)one--(a)two--(a)three--(a)four--(a)five--(a)six', '(b)one--(b)two', '(c)one--(c)two', '(d)one']
```

Comment: Thank you Moinuddin.

Answer (score 0):

zip and list the two lists into one dataframe.  groupby the variable and get the unique variables then concatenate the filter the dataframe for each value in the unique variable.  zip and list the results.

```
key_list=['a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'c', 'd']
value_list=['(a)one', '(a)two', '(a)three', '(a)four', '(a)five', '(a)six', '(b)one', '(b)two', '(c)one', '(c)two', '(d)one']

data=list(zip(key_list,value_list))
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['variable','phrase'])
unique_variables=list(df.groupby('variable').groups)
phrases=[]
for key in unique_variables:
    filter=df['variable']==key
    phrases.append("".join(df[filter]['phrase']))

print(list(zip(unique_variables,phrases)))
```

output:

```
[('a', '(a)one(a)two(a)three(a)four(a)five(a)six'), ('b', '(b)one(b)two'), ('c', '(c)one(c)two'), ('d', '(d)one')]
```

Comment: Thanks, Golden Lion that's useful code too